# Storing a nested FOR loop output in a 2D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, paramiko

I am using paramiko to login to a list of devices and then run a list of commands on each device and then capture the output. The python script is as follows:

```
import paramiko

f1 = open('hostfile','r')
f2 = open('commandfile','r')

devices = f1.readlines()
commands = f2.readlines()


for device in devices:
    for command in commands:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(device, username="admin", password="test")
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
        output= stdout.read()

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

What I want to achieve is to store the entire output in a 2 dimensional array as follows:

```
data = [
('device1', 'output1 for device1', 'output2 for device1', 'output3 for device1'),
('device2', 'output1 for device2', 'output2 for device2', 'output3 for device2'),
('device3', 'output1 for device3', 'output2 for device3', 'output3 for device3')
   ..................
   .................
]
```

I need to pass this output to an excel sheet using xlwt and hence my need to store the output in this format..

Comment: So what are you struggling with?

Comment: i am struggling with trying to store the output in the array as i have displayed above..

Comment: @Amistad normally you want to show us what you have tried thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
data = []
for device in devices:
    data.append([device])
    for command in commands:
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(device, username="admin", password="test")
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
        output= stdout.read()
        data[-1].append(output)
    data[-1] = tuple(data[-1])
```

Some explanation:

> what data[-1] and tuple(data[-1]) actually do

Note that `data` is supposed to be a list of tuples.

1. `data[-1]` refers to the last item of the list `data`.
2. `data[-1]` is built as a list in the inner loop. As your specified output structure of `data` is a list of tuples, the code uses the function `tuple()` to get a tuple converted from the list `data[-1]`.

Comment: YS-L..this is almost perfect albeit for one small hitch..i am not getting the device name in the first column..the device name is the name of the device it reads from the file hostfile..

Comment: data[-1].append(device)   ... This I added before the start of the second for loop and it worked.Truth be told I did this without understanding it as my knowledge of python structures is very elementary..If you have the time,can you let me know what data[-1] and tuple(data[-1]) actually do..